# Java Two Dimensional Array Boolean

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

My homework is to create a (not so) simple recreation of Conway's Game of Life. Exact Instructions:

> 1. Prompt the user to enter a list of (i,j) pairs (both non-negative integers)                (stop when a negative integer is read for either i
>      or j)
> 2. Prompt the user to enter the number of time steps
> 3. Initialize the grid based on the (i,j) pairs entered by the user
> 4. Display the initial state of the grid      (call the `displayGrid()` method)
> 5. For each time step, update the grid according to Conway’s rules (call the `updateGrid()` method) and display the grid (call the
>      `displayGrid()` method)

My programs output has now changed:

```
Please enter list of (i, j) pairs for populated cells(negative i or j to quit):
6 4 6 5 6 6 6 7 6 8
-1 -1
Enter number of time steps:
2
Initial Grid:






   ######



Time step 1










Time step 2
```

My new question is what is making my code "kill" everything? Why isn't there any "true"s?

Here's my code:

```
java.util.Scanner;

  class P8{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean[][] multi = new boolean[10][10];
       int i, j, N, x, y, h;

       for(x=1; x<multi.length; x++){
          for(y=1; y<multi.length; y++){
             multi[x][y] = false;
          }
       }
       System.out.println("Please enter list of (i, j) pairs for populated cells(negative i or j to quit):");

       while(true){
          i = in.nextInt();
          j = in.nextInt();
          if(i <= 0 || j <= 0){
             break;}

          multi[i][j] = true;
          }

       System.out.println("Enter number of time steps:");
       N = in.nextInt();
       System.out.println("Initial Grid: \n");
       displayGrid(multi);
       for(i = 1; i<N+1; i++){
          System.out.printf("Time step %d\n", i);
          updateGrid(multi);
          displayGrid(multi);
          System.out.println("\n");
       }
 }

       /******************************************
       void updateGrid(boolean mat[][]); updates
       the 2 dimensional array using Conway's
       standard rules. Does this by calling
       "neighbors" function
       ******************************************/
       public static void updateGrid(boolean mat[][]){
          boolean[][] temp = new boolean[mat.length][mat.length];
          int i, j, row, col, n=0;

          for(row = 0; row < mat.length; row++){
             for(col = 0; col < mat.length; col++){
             neighbors(mat, row, col);

             if(n>=4 || n<=1)
                mat[row][col] = false;
             else
                mat[row][col] = true;

             }
          }
       }

       /******************************************
        void neighbors(boolean mat[][]int row, int col) 
        checks how many "neighbors" are around a given point
       ******************************************/
        public static int neighbors(boolean mat[][], int row, int col){
           int N =0;
           if((row-1 >= 0)&&(col-1 >= 0))
              N = mat[row-1][col-1] ? N + 1 : N;

           if((row >=0)&&(col-1 >= 0))
              N = mat[row][col-1] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row+1 < mat.length)&&(col-1 >= 0))
              N = mat[row+1][col-1] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row+1 < mat.length)&&(col < mat[0].length))
              N = mat[row+1][col] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row+1 < mat.length)&&(col+1 < mat[0].length))
              N = mat[row+1][col+1] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row < mat.length)&&(col+1 < mat[0].length))
              N = mat[row][col+1] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row-1 >= 0)&&(col+1 < mat[0].length))
              N = mat[row-1][col+1] ? N+1 : N;

           if((row-1 >= 0)&&(col < mat[0].length))
              N = mat[row-1][col] ? N+1 : N;

            return N;
       }

       /******************************************
        void displayGrid(int mat[][]) prints out
        a two dimensional array
       ******************************************/
       public static void displayGrid(boolean mat[][]){
          int x, y;
          for(x=1; x<mat.length; x++){
             for(y = 1; y<mat.length; y++){
                if(mat[x][y])
                   System.out.printf("#");
                else
                   System.out.printf(" ");
             }
             System.out.println();
          }

       }
  }
```

`

Comment: There's no point in the `else if`. You can just use `else` since you're just inverting the original condition.

Comment: I took your opinion into account and updated my code. :D   Although a new problem has surfaced and I believe it's in my neighbors() function, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is where in my code is multi[][] becoming all 'true' since that's the criteria I have to print '#'

In your `displayGrid` method.

`if(mat[x][y]= true)` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Use

```
if (mat[x][y])
```

instead.

You never need to write `bool == true` (or `bool == false`), because you can write them more easily as `bool` (and `!bool`) - and the latter forms avoid the potential for missing out one of the `=` signs and changing the semantics of the expression.

Comment: Ahh okay I can see what you're getting at. I'll improve my code.